# Click to Change image not working in Android 2.2 App

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile

In **Android 2.2** app if I click an icon, I want it to change but when I clicked. The hover & active is not working.. it remains same no changes occur while I click...

Note : This code is working properly in Android 4.0, iOS, BB & Windows Mobile.

My Code

HTML :

```
<div>
    <span>
        <a href="page1.html">
         <span class="icon">&#32;</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.icon {background: url(../images/iconContain.png) no-repeat scroll -136px -197px transparent;display: block;height: 40px;width: 43px;}
.icon:active {background: url(../images/iconContain.png) no-repeat scroll -194px -197px transparent;display: block;height:40px;width:43px;}
.icon:hover {background: url(../images/iconContain.png) no-repeat scroll -194px -197px transparent;display: block;height:40px;width:43px;}
```

Comment: Why do you have .iocn:active and .iocn:hover instead of .icon:active and .icon:hover?

Comment: Sorry it's Spelling Mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you are going to be able to fix this. Android 2.3 is a first android version to implement CSS 2.1 selectors correctly. Android 2.2 and below had a lot problems with CSS selectors (not to mention CSS overall). Plus before version 2.3 browser developers were not forced to fully implement webkit functionality.

In case you have an Android 2.2 device with default webkit browser then this will work, in any other case you are out of luck.

Take a look at this link: http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html. It is overview of CSS 2.1 implementation on mobile phones (up to Android 2.1 and 2.2).